# How to configure spring security with header information

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to configure Spring Securita for API made with the help of Spring tools.

Fist of all I made a Spring security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //...gets all the users from DB with their authorities
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("**/Observation/**").hasAuthority("apiAllowed");           
    }
}
```

Then I use the following controller. Username should be transmitted as a header of the page:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class ObservationController {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ObservationController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/Observation/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={"text/html", "application/json", "application/ld+json"})
    public @ResponseBody Observation<?> getObservation(@PathVariable long id) {

        return getObservation(id);
    }       
}
```

Thirdly, I created a class SpringSecurityInitializer that doesn't requers any additional code, as I've read.

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
}
```

So in the end:

1. controller itself works well
2. but it doesn't demonstrate any reaction difference for different header values

And I think that a component showing that location of the username is a header of page is missing.
Am I right?

Comment: And why should it do anything? Your controller is mapped at `/resource/Observation` however you are securing `/Observation` those URLs don't match. Also if you don't do anything to display a username or whatever nothing is going to be shown.

Comment: how can I do anything to display a username?